# Way out of this world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I put down the title, I literally meant, way out of this world.

I have a command running on a 20Hz:

> tp @p[score_isCarrot_min=25]

And now, as anyone else might do, I wanted to test if the command worked...
You might have already seen this coming, but when I through down 25 carrots (that was what the objective was all about) it starts tp-ing me into the air *500 blocks per second!* Now that I think about it, it was extremely stupid to jump to the the gun and test it without thinking of the consequences... Any ideas about how I might come down?

[image]

^ This is where I was a little bit ago...

[image]

^ And this is one second later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net) to delete the command block. You can then teleport down using the command

`/tp [playername] ~0 64 ~0`

Comment: Oh, okay. When I downloaded it and opened it, it said that the program wasn't working though... I'll see what I can do. Thanks

Comment: Awesome, it works now, and I got the command block.

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN Awesome, glad I could help :)

Comment: You don't need the `0` in `~0`, `~` will do the same exact thing, and saves on characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you're alright killing all the Items in your loaded chunks, you can just kill them all:

```
/Kill @e[type=Item]
```

Depending on the command block, the score will not be 25 anymore and you will start falling. If you aren't falling then set your score manually:

```
/scoreboard players set @p <your username> IsCarrot 0
```

Then try using the command (tp to y level 64) from the other answer if you're too high up to just wait while falling

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
/scoreboard objectives remove isCarrot
```